# Wait async subscriptions when I emit next value

Tags: rxjs, subject

I have the next example

```
import { Subject } from "rxjs";

const subject = new Subject();

subject.subscribe(() => new Promise(res => {
  setTimeout(() => console.log('!! 1'), 500);
}))

subject.subscribe(() => new Promise(res => {
  setTimeout(() => console.log('!! 2'), 1000);
}))

console.log('>>> START')
subject.next();
console.log('<<< FINISH')
```

Console looks like

```
>>> START
<<< FINISH
!! 1
!! 2
```

I want the following behavious

```
>>> START
!! 1
!! 2
<<< FINISH
```

Can I reach expected behaviour or I should to use another aproach?

Comment: you can use the `toPromise()` method but then only the callback function inside the `subscribe` method will be executed and since it's `async`hronous it will be placed in the queue and won't be executed immediately

Comment: When using `.next()` you have no control over what async events is this going to trigger so you can't await it. It's hard to give any advice here, you'd have to restructure this example completely to make it do what you expect.

Comment: Maybe by using schedule approach? Can it provide a similar functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so, this should work. I just forced the behavior of the Observables. To be clear, observables are async javascript and need to share values in async mode so that you can 'emit' a new value through a subject and all the observables can see that value while doing some other tasks. This code do exactly what you asked for but it makes no sense to emit a value and await for that value in the same place and moment, to achieve that you should probably think about another way of coding this module.

Said that, i've tested this snippet and it works, hope this will help

```js
import { Subject } from "rxjs";
const subject = new Subject();

async function nextValue(value) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        subject.subscribe(subValue => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                 console.log(subValue);
                 resolve();
            }, 500);
        }, err => reject(err));
        subject.next(value);
    });
}    

(async () => {
    console.log('>>> START');
    await nextValue('myValue');
    console.log('<<< FINISH');
})();
```

Comment: It can solve part of my tasks, Thanks!